# Using winsock for socket programming in c

Tags: c, winsock, winsock2

I am writing a program in C that uses winsock and  I am using the command fcntl to make the receive call nonblocking and I am getting the following errors.

```
warning C4013: 'fcntl' undefined; assuming extern returning int 
error C2065: 'F_SETFL' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'F_GETFL' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'F_SETFL' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'O_NDELAY' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'EWOULDBLOCK' : undeclared identifierenter code here
```

I am including the winsock2.h header file in my code as follows

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
```

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I think on Windows you need to use [ioctlsocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than `fcntl()`.

To make non-blocking:

```
unsigned long on = 1;
if (0 != ioctlsocket(socket_fd, FIONBIO, &on))
{
    /* Handle failure. */
}
```

To make blocking:

```
unsigned long off = 0;
if (0 != ioctlsocket(socket_fd, FIONBIO, &off))
{
    /* Handle failure. */
}
```

Instead of `EWOULDBLOCK` use `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.